# Install bootable Ubuntu on external SSD without changing Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, installation, bootable-media

At work I have to use Ubuntu sometimes but I'd prefer to stick to Windows and don't want to have a dual boot setup. I don't really know if this is possible, that's why I am asking here before breaking my OS. I want to install Ubuntu on an external SSD Harddrive that will be connected to my computer via a USB3 port. When the SSD is plugged in I'd like the computer to directly boot into Ubuntu, whilst booting to Windows 10 when the harddrive is unplugged. In addition to that I'd like to have some space to share data between both operating systems.

I tried to search to problem online but came up only with dual boot solutions.

So is it possible to achieve what I want and can someone maybe show me a tutorial how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of the accepted answer of the Ask Ubuntu post
[How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

- Create the Ubuntu live installation media and use it to boot your computer
  and choose *Try Ubuntu*
- Plug in the external hard drive
- Start `gparted`. In most cases, the internal disk will be `sda` and the external
  `sdb`, but this is not guaranteed.
- Partition the external disk into one or two partitions and note their numbers:

  - If you need a swap partition, format it as `linux-swap`
  - The rest of the disk format as `ext4`
- Start the Ubuntu installer from the icon on the desktop or on the launcher.
  When asked how to install, choose *Something Else*.
- In the partition editor, highlight the `ext4` partition and click *Change*.
  Follow the dialogs to:

  - Use the partition as `ext4`
  - Mount to `/`
  - Format
- Still in the editor, highlight the swap partition and click *Change* and
  choose `linux-swap`
- Change the installation of the bootloader to the external disk, most likely
  `/dev/sdb`. It is important not to overwrite the bootloader on the internal
  hard drive.
- Double-check your partition choices, then click *Install Now*.
- Set the USB disk as the first in the BIOS boot order.

From now on, to run Ubuntu boot the computer with the USB plugged in.
The boot menu on the USB will show both Ubuntu on the external drive and Windows
on the internal drive, and you may choose the one you want.

If you boot without the USB, you will boot into Windows normally.

---

For another possibility using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL),
see the article
[How-to Install WSL Distros On External Disks](https://dev.to/domcorvasce/how-to-install-wsl-distros-on-external-disks-1d22)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only want to do that just install Ubuntu on the harddrive and change the BIOS settings to boot from the harddrive. When the drive is present the system will boot from this device, if not boot from the local hard drive.

I used Ubuntu on work too, and in order to have both I got a Virtual Machine with Linux having Windows as a host.

Comment: Unfortunatly, a virtual machine is too slow to do the stuff I need to process.
However I've read stuff about the Ubuntu Boot Manager being installed on the first harddrive anyway and Windows not being able to boot any longer without the external harddrive connected.

Is there a need to disconnect the Windows Harddrive before installing Ubuntu on the external harddrive?

Comment: No, Is like the same process when you create a live usb, you need to install the grub to the harddrive so the machine can boot from there. Did you try to create like a live usb with your drive? using rufus for example?

Comment: Not yet, cause I was afraid to damage my installation. Do you know any good tutorial for that? I only installed Ubuntu on a main harddrive.

Comment: You can take a look https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/ 
Please consider that if you create this the entire disk will be erased. If you don't pretend to use the entire disk I would suggest to have a usb with at least 64 G to store all you need. If you want to use the hard disk then you will need to open the Rufus, click on the interface and do CTRL+ALT+F to display the drive. Remember that Ubuntu doesn't ask for too much drive space for the operating system so could use an 8G and test the performance.